# How to round this one?

Tags: javascript, html

I get a pretty big number from the api and pass it to the interface, how can I round it up to six decimal places?

```
if(key == 'hashrentReward')
        {
            spans = document.getElementById('hashrentReward').getElementsByTagName('span');
            console.log(spans[0].innerText);
            values[key] = values[key] * '864000';
                
        }
```

Comment: Now it's 4.1212800000000005, want to make it 4.12128 actually.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask **+** [minimal and **REPRODUCTIBLE** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)